# HtmlOutputText.setValue() not properly updated

Tags: java, jsf

Please take a look at the sample code. I have blank HtmlOutputText outputText1 on page.
I tried to set value by using the following code.

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
s = "" + r.nextInt(1000);
outputText1.setValue(s);
```

The random number was properly generated whenever I refresh. But the outputText1 is not refreshing. It is always showing the first number even tho I refresh the page.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Is the action you're invoking immediate=true?

Comment: do you rerender the page after the setvalue?